# Custom star rating Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, rating

I am trying to do the custom star rating with angular.js, where I will have different set of images. I need to change it dynamically on hover the image. I am having 5 images

> X X X X X

if I move the mouse pointer to 4th X I should be able to dynamically change

> - - - - X

I used directive to achieve it.

> .directive('fundooRating', function () {
>
> ```
> return {
>   restrict: 'A',
>   template: '<ul class="rating">' +
>               '<li ng-repeat="star in stars" ng-class="star" 
>                  ng-click="toggle($index)"><img ng-mouseenter="hoveringOver($index)"
> ```
>
> ng-src="{{con}}" />' +
>                   '',
>         scope: {
>           ratingValue: '=',
>           max: '=',
>           readonly: '@',
>           onRatingSelected: '&'
>         },
>         link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
>
> ```
>     var updateStars = function() {
>       scope.stars = [];
>       for (var  i = 0; i < scope.max; i++) {
>         scope.stars.push({filled: i < scope.ratingValue});
>       }
>     };
>     scope.con = "Images/Rating/empty.png";
>     scope.hoveringOver = function(index){
>       var countIndex = index+1;
>       scope.Condition = "Good.png"
>       console.log("Hover  " + countIndex);
>     };
>     scope.toggle = function(index) {
>       if (scope.readonly && scope.readonly === 'true') {
>         return;
>       }
>       scope.ratingValue = index + 1;
>       scope.onRatingSelected({rating: index + 1});
>     };
>
>     scope.$watch('ratingValue', function(oldVal, newVal) {
>       if (newVal) {
>         updateStars();
>       }
>     });
>   }
> }   });
> ```

How can I able to find which image my mouse pointer is and how to change the rest of Images. I want to do the custom rating option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a condition for each star in your updateStars function, either as a property for each, or a separate array. Then, you can do something like this:

```
scope.hoveringOver = function(index){
    for (var i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
        scope.stars[i].Condition = "Good.png";
    }
};
```

Or the separate array way (assuming the array is `scope.conditions`):

```
scope.hoveringOver = function(index){
    for (var i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
        scope.conditions[i] = "Good.png";
    }
};
```

You also need a function opposite of hoveringOver to remove the states to default/previous versions.

Comment: Hi, well you can build the full path using that Condition (or make Condition be the full path), and just use it in `ng-src` like this: `<img ng-src="{{star.fullPath}}" />`. Basically, have a controllable src for each image instead of one you have now (`scope.con`).

Comment: Hi I have like 5 images next to next.. how to change image for first image till 4th image.

Comment: Both examples I gave you will change all the images left of the hovered image (including the hovered image).

Answer (score 2):

Angular UI gives you premade directives for the same purpose, did you try it?

> http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Go down to the Rating Title in the same page, i think it might solve your purpose.